# when set one svg display: none, other SVG elements become black

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

When i set display: none; on one svg element
the other svg elements acts weird and become black.
here is jsfiddle link. There is 2 svg element when you click button other one becomes black.

```js
document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#el1').style.display = "none"
})
```

```css
.el{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el" id="el1">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 308.4 308.4">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="10" y1="142.86" x2="-275.71" y2="142.86" gradientTransform="matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d1d3d4" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="7.71" y1="142.86" x2="-273.43" y2="142.86" gradientTransform="matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#d1d3d4" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <title>Asset 2</title>
        <g style="isolation: isolate;" class="cls-1">
            <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
                <g id="rectangle">
                    <g class="cls-2">
                        <rect style="fill: #fff;opacity: 0;" x="23.03" y="23.04" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #fdfdfd;opacity: 0.02;" x="22.58" y="22.59" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #fafafa;opacity: 0.04;" x="22.13" y="22.15" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #f8f8f8;opacity: 0.06;" x="21.68" y="21.7" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #f5f5f5;opacity: 0.08;" x="21.24" y="21.25" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #f3f3f3;opacity: 0.1;" x="20.79" y="20.8" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #f0f0f1;opacity: 0.12;" x="20.34" y="20.35" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #eee;opacity: 0.14;" x="19.89" y="19.91" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #ebebec;opacity: 0.16;" x="19.44" y="19.46" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #e9e9e9;opacity: 0.18;" x="18.99" y="19.01" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #e6e6e7;opacity: 0.2;" x="18.55" y="18.56" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #e4e4e5;opacity: 0.22;" x="18.1" y="18.11" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #e1e2e2;opacity: 0.24;" x="17.65" y="17.66" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #dfdfe0;opacity: 0.25;" x="17.2" y="17.22" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #dcddde;opacity: 0.27;" x="16.75" y="16.77" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #dadadb;opacity: 0.29;" x="16.31" y="16.32" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #d7d8d9;opacity: 0.31;" x="15.86" y="15.87" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #d5d5d6;opacity: 0.33;" x="15.41" y="15.42" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #d2d3d4;opacity: 0.35;" x="14.96" y="14.98" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #d0d0d2;opacity: 0.37;" x="14.51" y="14.53" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #cdcecf;opacity: 0.39;" x="14.06" y="14.08" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #cbcccd;opacity: 0.41;" x="13.62" y="13.63" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #c8c9ca;opacity: 0.43;" x="13.17" y="13.18" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #c6c7c8;opacity: 0.45;" x="12.72" y="12.73" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #c3c4c6;opacity: 0.47;" x="12.27" y="12.29" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #c1c2c3;opacity: 0.49;" x="11.82" y="11.84" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #bebfc1;opacity: 0.51;" x="11.38" y="11.39" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #bcbdbe;opacity: 0.53;" x="10.93" y="10.94" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #b9babc;opacity: 0.55;" x="10.48" y="10.49" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #b7b8ba;opacity: 0.57;" x="10.03" y="10.05" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #b4b5b7;opacity: 0.59;" x="9.58" y="9.6" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #b2b3b5;opacity: 0.61;" x="9.13" y="9.15" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #afb1b2;opacity: 0.63;" x="8.69" y="8.7" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #adaeb0;opacity: 0.65;" x="8.24" y="8.25" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #aaacae;opacity: 0.67;" x="7.79" y="7.8" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #a8a9ab;opacity: 0.69;" x="7.34" y="7.36" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #a5a7a9;opacity: 0.71;" x="6.89" y="6.91" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #a3a4a6;opacity: 0.73;" x="6.45" y="6.46" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #a0a2a4;opacity: 0.75;" x="6" y="6.01" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #9e9fa2;opacity: 0.76;" x="5.55" y="5.56" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #9b9d9f;opacity: 0.78;" x="5.1" y="5.12" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #999b9d;opacity: 0.8;" x="4.65" y="4.67" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #96989b;opacity: 0.82;" x="4.21" y="4.22" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #949698;opacity: 0.84;" x="3.76" y="3.77" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #919396;opacity: 0.86;" x="3.31" y="3.32" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #8f9193;opacity: 0.88;" x="2.86" y="2.87" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #8c8e91;opacity: 0.9;" x="2.41" y="2.43" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #8a8c8f;opacity: 0.92;" x="1.96" y="1.98" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #87898c;opacity: 0.94;" x="1.52" y="1.53" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #85878a;opacity: 0.96;" x="1.07" y="1.08" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #828487;opacity: 0.98;" x="0.62" y="0.63" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #808285;" x="0.17" y="0.19" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65" ry="53.65" />
                    </g>
                    <rect style="fill: url(#linear-gradient);" width="285.71" height="285.71" rx="53.71" ry="53.71" />
                    <rect style="fill: url(#linear-gradient-2);" x="2.29" y="2.29" width="281.14" height="281.14" rx="51.43"
                        ry="51.43" />
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="el">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 308.4 308.4">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="10" y1="142.86" x2="-275.71" y2="142.86" gradientTransform="matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d1d3d4" />
            </linearGradient>
            <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="7.71" y1="142.86" x2="-273.43" y2="142.86" gradientTransform="matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 10, 0)"
                gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="#d1d3d4" />
                <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <title>Asset 2</title>
        <g style="isolation: isolate;" class="cls-1">
            <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
                <g id="rectangle">
                    <g class="cls-2">
                        <rect style="fill: #fff;opacity: 0;" x="23.03" y="23.04" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #fdfdfd;opacity: 0.02;" x="22.58" y="22.59" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #fafafa;opacity: 0.04;" x="22.13" y="22.15" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #f8f8f8;opacity: 0.06;" x="21.68" y="21.7" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #f5f5f5;opacity: 0.08;" x="21.24" y="21.25" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #f3f3f3;opacity: 0.1;" x="20.79" y="20.8" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #f0f0f1;opacity: 0.12;" x="20.34" y="20.35" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #eee;opacity: 0.14;" x="19.89" y="19.91" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #ebebec;opacity: 0.16;" x="19.44" y="19.46" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #e9e9e9;opacity: 0.18;" x="18.99" y="19.01" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #e6e6e7;opacity: 0.2;" x="18.55" y="18.56" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #e4e4e5;opacity: 0.22;" x="18.1" y="18.11" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #e1e2e2;opacity: 0.24;" x="17.65" y="17.66" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #dfdfe0;opacity: 0.25;" x="17.2" y="17.22" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #dcddde;opacity: 0.27;" x="16.75" y="16.77" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #dadadb;opacity: 0.29;" x="16.31" y="16.32" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #d7d8d9;opacity: 0.31;" x="15.86" y="15.87" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #d5d5d6;opacity: 0.33;" x="15.41" y="15.42" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #d2d3d4;opacity: 0.35;" x="14.96" y="14.98" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #d0d0d2;opacity: 0.37;" x="14.51" y="14.53" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #cdcecf;opacity: 0.39;" x="14.06" y="14.08" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #cbcccd;opacity: 0.41;" x="13.62" y="13.63" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #c8c9ca;opacity: 0.43;" x="13.17" y="13.18" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #c6c7c8;opacity: 0.45;" x="12.72" y="12.73" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #c3c4c6;opacity: 0.47;" x="12.27" y="12.29" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #c1c2c3;opacity: 0.49;" x="11.82" y="11.84" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #bebfc1;opacity: 0.51;" x="11.38" y="11.39" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #bcbdbe;opacity: 0.53;" x="10.93" y="10.94" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #b9babc;opacity: 0.55;" x="10.48" y="10.49" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #b7b8ba;opacity: 0.57;" x="10.03" y="10.05" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #b4b5b7;opacity: 0.59;" x="9.58" y="9.6" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #b2b3b5;opacity: 0.61;" x="9.13" y="9.15" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #afb1b2;opacity: 0.63;" x="8.69" y="8.7" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #adaeb0;opacity: 0.65;" x="8.24" y="8.25" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #aaacae;opacity: 0.67;" x="7.79" y="7.8" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #a8a9ab;opacity: 0.69;" x="7.34" y="7.36" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #a5a7a9;opacity: 0.71;" x="6.89" y="6.91" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #a3a4a6;opacity: 0.73;" x="6.45" y="6.46" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #a0a2a4;opacity: 0.75;" x="6" y="6.01" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #9e9fa2;opacity: 0.76;" x="5.55" y="5.56" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #9b9d9f;opacity: 0.78;" x="5.1" y="5.12" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #999b9d;opacity: 0.8;" x="4.65" y="4.67" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #96989b;opacity: 0.82;" x="4.21" y="4.22" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #949698;opacity: 0.84;" x="3.76" y="3.77" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #919396;opacity: 0.86;" x="3.31" y="3.32" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #8f9193;opacity: 0.88;" x="2.86" y="2.87" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #8c8e91;opacity: 0.9;" x="2.41" y="2.43" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #8a8c8f;opacity: 0.92;" x="1.96" y="1.98" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #87898c;opacity: 0.94;" x="1.52" y="1.53" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #85878a;opacity: 0.96;" x="1.07" y="1.08" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #828487;opacity: 0.98;" x="0.62" y="0.63" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65"
                            ry="53.65" />
                        <rect style="fill: #808285;" x="0.17" y="0.19" width="285.37" height="285.4" rx="53.65" ry="53.65" />
                    </g>
                    <rect style="fill: url(#linear-gradient);" width="285.71" height="285.71" rx="53.71" ry="53.71" />
                    <rect style="fill: url(#linear-gradient-2);" x="2.29" y="2.29" width="281.14" height="281.14" rx="51.43"
                        ry="51.43" />
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<button id="click">Just Click Me</button>
```

link: https://jsfiddle.net/9ungzkfv/

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. No jsfiddle link.

Comment: Can you provide some code accompanying your question?

Comment: Use `display: hidden` instead.

Comment: You have gradients with the same `id`in both SVG. Please try using uniques `id`-s

Comment: Actually i am repeating this element, so there will be lots of them.
Visibility:hidden solved the problem, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have repeating IDs. Every element has to have a unique ID. You have two elements with `id="linear-gradient"`, two elements with `id="layer_2"` etc.